# ¿Como puedo agregar a un array de varios objetos?

Tags: php, mysql, json

soy nuevo en esto y estoy intentando hacer una funcion recursiva en php

```
public function recursive_tree($valor) {
    $consulta = $this->Modelo->Getdata('getHijos', $valor);
    if ($consulta->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($consulta->result() as $p) {
            $arbol[] = array("id_user" => $p->id_user, "nombre" => $p->nombre, "id_raiz" => $p->id_raiz);
            $this->recursive_tree($p->id_user);
        }
        echo json_encode($arbol);
    }
}
```

,
 obtengo todos los datos que necesito pero la respuesta queda es

```
[{"id_user":"31","nombre":"lorena","id_raiz":"29"},
    {"id_user":"32","nombre":"pedro","id_raiz":"29"}]

[{"id_user":"33","nombre":"juan","id_raiz":"30"},
{"id_user":"34","nombre":"jose","id_raiz":"30"},],
```

como dos objetos distintos, lo que intento obtener es unir ambos.

```
[{"id_user":"31","nombre":"lorena","id_raiz":"29"},{"id_user":"32","nombre":"pedro","id_raiz":"29"},
{"id_user":"33","nombre":"juan","id_raiz":"30"},{"id_user":"34","nombre":"jose","id_raiz":"30"},]
```

espero haberme expresado bien y gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: La primera es tu salida actual? así tal cual? no logro entender porque te los agrupa de 2 en 2, podrías poner algunos datos de prueba?

Comment: Estás llamando la función dos veces con `$valor` 29 y luego 30? O una sola vez? Muéstranos los datos de origen y la primera llamada que haces a  `recursive_tree` con su respectivo parámetro

Answer (score 1):

Sería bueno ver el contenido de la tabla que estás consultando. Pero el problema aquí es básicamente que cada vez que llamas a `recursive_tree` imprimes el resultado en vez de irlo añadiendo a un mismo arreglo.

Se diría que estás llamando dos veces al método, una pasándole `$valor` 29 y otra con `$valor` 30. Si tu estructura tiene una relación de parentezco:

```
- nodo 29
  - nodo 31
  - nodo 32
- nodo 30
  - nodo 33
  - nodo 34
```

Entonces es natural que llamar

```
$instancia->recursive_tree(29);
$instancia->recursive_tree(30);
```

Te genere dos arreglos.

Como `get_recursive_tree` es un método de instancia, puedes acceder a una propiedad de instancia `$arbol` previamente declarada. Llenarla con todos los resultados que necesites, y sólo al final imprimir el valor:

```
class miClase {
    $arbol = [];

    public function recursive_tree($valor) {
        $consulta = $this->Modelo->Getdata('getHijos', $valor);
        if ($consulta->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($consulta->result() as $p) {
                $this->arbol[] = array("id_user" => $p->id_user, "nombre" => $p->nombre, "id_raiz" => $p->id_raiz);
                $this->recursive_tree($p->id_user);
            }
        }
    }

   public function imprime_arbol() {
      $this->recursive_tree(29);
      $this->recursive_tree(30);

     echo json_encode($this->arbol);

   }
}
```

Obviamente sería mejor si tanto 29 como 30 tuvieran un padre común, o pudieses obtener todos los padres de una consulta previa, para no llamar manualmente a `recursive_tree` por cada padre que conozcas.

Answer (score -1):

Espero esto sea lo que buscas amigo

Puedes usar la función `concat()`

---

El método concat() se usa para unir dos o más arreglos. Este método no cambia los arreglos existentes, sino que devuelve un nuevo arreglo.

Dato en los arreglos que pasaste tienen una coma al final tienes que quitarsela

```js
var objeto1 = [{"id_user":"33","nombre":"juan","id_raiz":"30"},{"id_user":"34","nombre":"jose","id_raiz":"30"}]

var objeto2 = [{"id_user":"33","nombre":"juan","id_raiz":"30"},{"id_user":"34","nombre":"jose","id_raiz":"30"}]

var objetoFinal =  objeto1.concat(objeto2);

$("#button").click(function(){
   $(".div").text(JSON.stringify(objetoFinal))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  
</div>
<button id="button" type="button" name="button">Objeto Unido</button>
```

Comment: de la manera que me lo planteas estaria bien, pero donde es un ciclo con las consultas a la bd tendran n cantidad de respuestas y por cada respuesta consultara de nuevo y asi sucesivamente "recursividad", el problema que tengo es que cada vez que encuentra un "nodo hijo" me crea un objeto nuevo y no me deja un objeto con todos los datos.

Comment: espero que con la function `concat()` pueda solucionarte el probelma

Comment: uhhh pero esta respuesta está en javascript y la pregunta está en php

Comment: el objetivo es el mismo que al final tengas un solo objeto con todos los arreglos unidos y el puso el tag `javascript` lo que importa es solucionar el problema